# Streaming audio file during call through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc, web-audio-api

What I am trying to do:

1. I am making a call from my browser by clicking on any number
2. call gets connected, and I can talk and listen whatever receiver is
   talking

I have used WebRtc API for accessing Audio through the browser,

Now What I want more to do :

1) When I call and reach answering machine, then I want to leave a pre-recorded voicemail through a click.

So I want that, I just stream that audio file through my microphone, But I am not getting how to do this,

```
this.audioTest = function() {
    console.log("Testing function");
    var a1 =  document.getElementById("remote");
    var pc = this.session.sessionDescriptionHandler.peerConnection;
    var backgroundMusic = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById("remoteMedia"));
    var mixedOutput = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
    backgroundMusic.connect(mixedOutput);
    console.log(mixedOutput);
    var remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    pc.getSenders().forEach(function (sender) {
        var track = mixedOutput.stream;
        if (track) {
            remoteStream.addTrack(track);
        }
    });
    a1.srcObject = remoteStream;
}
```

Here is my code, I am playing the audio first and then, trying to stream it through my microphone,
But not getting any lead,
If anyone can help or suggest my anything, It would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Web Audio API.  There, you can mix (or, switch in your case) between the microphone and audio from other sources seamlessly while sending only one MediaStream to the WebRTC peer.

The relevant method is `createMediaStreamDestination` on the context.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination

```
const rtcOutput = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
yourMixOutput.conntect(rtcOutput);
```

Then, use `rtcOutput.stream` in what you send to the peer.

Comment: Thanks @Brad for your answer, I am looking into this, Will mark it as answer, If am able to et it.

Comment: Hy brad, I tried what you sugested me, but I am not able to get it work, It gives following error :
"Failed to execute 'addTrack' on 'MediaStream': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStreamTrack'." 
I have updated my code above, please help

Comment: @Unknown `track` in your code is not a MediaStreamTrack, it's a MediaStream itself.  Instead of creating an empty MediaStream for `remoteStream`, you should simply use `mixedOutput.stream` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to stream your audio file(voice message) through your microphone.You can switch stream (passed to WebRTC) from microphone to voice message.

```
const micStream; // user MediaStream
const msgStream; // voice message MediaStream
const pc; //RTCPeerConnection
const destination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
const micSource = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
const micGainNode = audioCtx.createGain(); //with this you can change volume of stream
micSource.connect(micGainNode);
micGainNode.connect(destination);
// adding stream of destination to WebRTC.
// note that stream is taken from destination
destination.stream.getTracks().forEach(
   function (track) {
      pc.addTrack(track,destination.stream);
   }
);
// then on send voice message listener  
sendVoiceMessageListener = function(){
   //we need to disconnect microphone stream and connect voice message stream
    micGainNode.disconnect(destination);
    const msgSource = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(msgStream);
    const msgGainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
    micSource.connect(micGainNode);
    micGainNode.connect(destination);
}
```